# Exporting angular 2+ template for outsource designers

Tags: html, css, angular

We are interested to export some angular 2+ components (html + css) of our pretty big project to outsource company.
There is a lot of nested component and directives in the html templates.
The solution should be easy to integrate back after the redesign. Also need to prevent exposing our proprietary code related to these components.
Any ideas?

Comment: Look into [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements).

Comment: Create a GitHub repo and ignore everything but the relevant files maybe? By the way this will probably get closed as off topic.